# Is It possible to create class name starts with digits in c++

Tags: c++

I need to create a class name starting with digits as 206xx.if it is possible to create then how to achieve this.

Comment: You _need to_, why?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not possible. A valid identifier must begin with a non-digit character, and class names are identifiers.

To quote the standard, section 2.10:

```
identifier:
  identifier-nondigit
  identifier identifier-nondigit
  identifier digit

identifier-nondigit:
  nondigit
  universal-character-name
  other implementation-defined characters

nondigit: one of 
     a b c d e f g h i j k l m
     n o p q r s t u v w x y z
     A B C D E F G H I J K L M
     N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z

digit: one of 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

> An identifier is an arbitrarily long sequence of letters and digits. Each universal-character-name in an identifier shall designate a character whose encoding in ISO 10646 falls into one of the ranges specified in E.1. The initial element shall not be a universal-character-name designating a character whose encoding falls into one of the ranges specified in E.2. Upper- and lower-case letters are different. All characters are significant.

So, from the grammar above, we see that `identifier-nondigit` must precede `digit` in all derivations of `identifier`. Hence, identifiers cannot start with digits.

Comment: Pointing out that/how the mentioned sections imply digit/alpha would top this off.

Comment: Yeah, I was looking for the quote ;)

Comment: You could also quote [lex.name](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.name), which describes the grammar for an identifier.